# Vuejs watch dynamic array element on change

Tags: arrays, vuejs2

I'm creating this text editor, with the field of name, and address

```
<ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="data[index].name">
<ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="data[index].address.1">
<ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="data[index].address.2">
```

and the data property

```
 data() {
    return {
        data:[],
        index:0,
        editor: customedit
    };
  },
```

the editor also have two button, next and back, with the method add and substracting "index".
the data, is loaded before mount from server, with structure like this

```
serverdata = [{name:'name1',address:{1:'address 1',2:'address 2'}} , {name:'name2',address:{1:'address 4',2:'address 4'}}]
```

so what I want to do is, after data from server is loaded, user can move between data, and when user make change to it, the data index that user make change to will be logged.
so far I have been using deep watcher like this:

```
watch: {
    data: {
      handler(val) {
          console.log('the data is changed');
          console.log(this.index + 1);
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
```

but even when there are no change, when I click next, the log is shown,
thanks for any help/suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you may compare new and old value if they are different do the console.log.
You can receive two parameters in the function something like this:

```
handler(newValue, oldValue) {
         if(newValue !== oldValue) {
          console.log('the data is changed');
          console.log(this.index + 1);
         }
      },
     deep: true
```

You can compare the content in the array with:

```
if(JSON.stringify(newValue) !== JSON.stringify(oldValue)) {
          console.log('the data is changed');
          console.log(this.index + 1);
         }
      },
     deep: true
```

Okay your problems seems you are receiving the same values in old and new values. You can try to watch a computed property and use that to convert array into string.Even with that string you can reconstruct the old array. I try to do a example:

```
data() {
    return {
        yourArray: []
    }
},
computed: {
    yourArrayStr: function () { 
        return JSON.stringify(this.yourArray)
    }
},
watch: {
    yourArrayStr: function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue !== oldValue){
            let oldValueArray = JSON.parse(oldValue);
            console.log();
            console.log();
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, but weirdly it not working, when I check on console.log, both newValue and oldValue contain the newValue, so the condition was not met

Comment: "Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value."
heres from vue documentation, so how could I track the change inside object?

Comment: thanks for the update, but still wont work, I think because what the documentation says, the oldval is same as newval

Comment: I updated it again XD. Try it and say if work.

Comment: YES!!!! its work! omg, thank you very much,, been on this problem for more than 24 hours, and you solve it in 15 minutes,, :DDD